# Returning data based on multiple drop down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of drop down menus that once selected should return different types of data based on the user's selection. Here's the format:

```
var data = {
        name :{
                first:{
                    itemOne    : [],
                    itemTwo    : [],
                    itemThree  : []
                }

                second:{
                    itemOne    : [],
                    itemTwo    : [],
                    itemThree  : []
                }

                third:{
                    itemOne    : [],
                    itemTwo    : [],
                    itemThree  : []
                }
        }
 }
```

So there are two drop down menus. The first menu has the names 'first', 'second', 'third' and the second menu has 'itemOne', 'itemTwo', and 'itemThree'. So I would like data to be returned or updated each time the user selects from these two drop down menus. I currently have the following for just one menu:

```
 $('#selectMenu').on('change', function (event) {

        var selectedData = data[$(this).val()];
        console.log(selectedData);

        });
```

How could I make this so that the data returned depends on both drop down menus rather than just one?

Edit: HTML Markup

```
<span display: inline-block; width: 150px>
  <center>
    <select id="selectMenuTwo"> 
        <option value="first">first</option>
        <option value="second">second</option>
        <option value="third">third</option>
    </select>

    <select id="selectMenu">
        <option>Menu 1</option>
        <option value="itemOne">Item One</option>
        <option value="itemTwo">Item Two</option>
        <option value="itemThree">Item Three</option>
    </select>
 </center>
</span>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML markup.

Comment: @Incognito It has been added.

Comment: Unless one of your option values is "name", `data[$(this).val()]` is going to return `undefined`. I think you're looking for `data.name[$(this).val()]` instead, at least for the first level of traversal.

Comment: Is there a reason the option elements in `#selectMenuTwo` don't have value attributes? Also, if the "Menu 1" option is selected in `#selectMenu`, what do you want to happen?

Comment: @tavnab -- I just wanted to be able to return the nested object based on the multiple drop down selections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the change event on both dropdowns and then just look at the other menu's selected value inside the "change" function.

```
    $('#selectMenu1').on('change', function (event) {

        var menu2SelectedData = $('#selectMenu2').val();
        var selectedData = data[$(this).val()];
        console.log(selectedData);

    });

    $('#selectMenu2').on('change', function (event) {

        var menu1SelectedData = $('#selectMenu1').val();
        var selectedData = data[$(this).val()];
        console.log(selectedData);

    });
```

or maybe something like this would be even cleaner...

```
    // handle change for both menues
    $('#selectMenu1, #selectMenu2').on('change', function (event) {

        var menu1SelectedData = $('#selectMenu1').val();
        var menu2SelectedData = $('#selectMenu2').val();
        var dataForDropdown = data.name[menu1SelectedData][menu2SelectedData];

    });
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to use these values, maybe this answer should also show how to extract the correct array from the `data` object in the question (e.g. `var selectedData = data.name[menu1SelectedData][menu2SelectedData];`)

Comment: @delux247, this was totally what I was looking to do. Excellent. I may have not phrased the question properly, but this works. Thanks!

Comment: This is a good answer, but because it's possible to select an option that doesn't have a `value="..."` attribute (i.e. `<option>Menu 1</option>`), you should be prepared to check this before traversing your `data` object. In other words, check that `data.name.hasOwnProperty(menu1SelectedData)` is true before trying to access the members of `data.name[menu1SelectedData]`. Otherwise, you will get a `ReferenceError` for trying to lookup a non-existent value.